Finding span of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$
Find a list of four distinct vectors in $\mathbb{F}^3$ whose span equal $$S=\{(x,y,z)~:~x+y+z=0\}$$
Where $\mathbb{F}$ can be the real line or complex plane.
This is the first problem from of chapter 2A in Linear Algebra done Right 4th edition. I want to solve this question only using what's from section 2A ( which basically talks about definition of linear combination of vectors, span of vectors, linear independence and dependence) and I can not find a fourth vector that satisfies the question.
I am answering this question assuming I don't know what a matrix representation or linear transformation is yet.
My solution:
Let $(x,y,z)\in S$ then I have the following possibilities:

$x=-y-z$ then $(x,y,z)=(-y-z,y,z)=y(-1,1,0)+z(-1,0,1)$

$y=-x-z$ then $(x,y,z)=(x,-x-z,z)=x(1,-1,0)+z(0,-1,1)$

$z=-x-y$ then $(x,y,z)=(x,y,-x-y)=x(1,0,-1)+y(0,1,-1)$


Then I dont really know how to go on. Well, my best guess(which I don't know why this works) is that take the vectors I found above and get rid of scalar multiples. Which leaves me
$$(-1,1,0),(1,0,-1),(0,-1,1)$$
I checked that the span of above 3 vectors is a subset of $S$. Converse should be immediate since I got these vectors from looking at arbitrary elements in $S$.
But after playing around with similar ideas I cant find a fourth vector. Also why above method yields a span for $S$?
Thanks in advance!

For the fourth vector anything satisfying $x+y+z=0$ will do.  Even $\vec 0.$

Hint: you've imposed an unfortunate handicap on yourself. Does the problem or the definition of a span require each of the vectors to have a certain property?
Extra Hint: what's the difference between $$\operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$ and $$\operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$ ?

The definition of span only states it is the set of all linear combination of given vectors. Ah, I see I should just add a scalar multiple to the list I have since it doesnt really change anything?

@RemuX indeed. Crucially you were imposing a linear independence constraint on yourself which was both impossible and unnecessary for a span.
